# Digital signature removed during encryption process

Tags: encryption, certificate

I have a problem with encrypting an email that contains 2 attachments and a digital signature.  I pass the digitally signed email into Microsoft's envelope.encrypt.  It's using AES-256 encryption and returns an encrypted file that I then email to the recipient.  When the recipient checks the email's message properties, it shows that it is encrypted but it's missing our digital signature.  Why is our digital certificate being removed during the encryption process and how can I fix this so it remains?  The email must be encrypted using AES-256 encryption and must contain our digital signature.

We tried the following:
**1st attempt** - Add our digital signature to the email that has 2 file attachments.  Pass digitally signed email to Microsoft's encryption process envelope.encrypt() using AES-256 encryption RSA/SHA256.  Send email.  Email is decrypted.  Message properties show the email was encrypted using AES-256 BUT there's NO digital certificate.  Both attachments are included in email

**2nd attempt** - Add our digital signature to the email that has 2 file attachments.  Pass digitally signed email to Microsoft's encryption process envelope.encrypt() using AES-256 encryption RSA/SHA384.  Send email.  Email is decrypted.  Message properties show the email was encrypted using AES-256 BUT there's NO digital certificate. Both attachments are included in email.

**3rd attempt** - Add our digital signature to the email that has 2 file attachments.  Pass digitally signed email to Microsoft's encryption process envelope.encrypt() using AES-256 encryption RSA/SHA1.  Send email.  Email is decrypted.  Message properties show the email was encrypted using AES-256 BUT there's NO digital certificate. Both attachments are included in email.

**4th attempt** - Add our digital signature to the email that has 2 file attachments.  Pass digitally signed email to Microsoft's encryption process envelope.encrypt() using AES-256 encryption RSA/SHA256.  Add our digital certificate again. Send email.  Email is received.  Message properties show digital certificate is there BUT it is not encrypted and there are no attachments.